# MOSFET Off When Load Voltage Applied

Tags: mosfet, pwm

I have a N-Channel MOSFET gate connected to a Teensy 3.6 analog pwm pin with the intention of setting the duty cycle on the output of the pin to control the switching of the MOSFET. For reference this is 500 Hz I believe although it is irrelevant.

I have noticed that while the MOSFET works as expected and has low resistance (micro-ohms) when the load voltage (6V) is off as soon as the power supply (12V stepped down to 6V using a buck converter) is turned on the resistance shoots up to its off state. The load is a only 4 ohm resistive heater.

[Simple schematic to get the gist of my setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8SBC.png)
[image]

The 5V input to the gate is from a level shifter connecting the pin of the Teensy to the MOSFET's gate. There is a 10K Ohm resistor in parallel between ground and the gate and the voltage to the heater is 6V.

I am new to electronics and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the part number of the mosfet?

Comment: It could be usefull to give information on what MOSFET you are using. The resistance of the heater is likely significantly lower on startup too - what could be happening is that you are triggering some form of protection circuitry.

Comment: My apologies here is the link to the mosfet I am using. http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Nexperia/PHP79NQ08LT127/?qs=6YAT8rHPFU81nxYQ4Ym4Yg%3d%3d

Comment: Are you trying to measure resistance with 6 volts applied? Instead of talking about the resistance you think you see, apply 5 volts to the gate, 6 volts to the heater, and measure the voltage from ground to the bottom of the heater. What voltage do you see?

Comment: I see 6 volts. It may also be worth mentioning I have a calibrated thermistor from which I am reading the temperature of the heater and when I apply the 6 volts the temperature does not increase.

Comment: What is the resistance of the heater? When cold I mean.

Comment: OK, so your FET is dead or miswired, probably. You have not identified your FET, so there's a possibility that the gate requires more than 5 volts to turn on. Check your data sheet for Vgs(th), or go directly to sparking, and try the test with 10 to 12 volts on the gate. Oh, and one more thing - just exactly what is your FET? If it's a depletion mode FET that might explain it, but virtually all common FETs these days are enhancement mode.-

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It could be miswired but I am certain it is an enhancement mode MOSFET and the threshold voltage on the gate is 2 V so 5V is well above. I posted the link to the MOSFET which has the datasheet as well in an earlier comment. I am not sure how it is miswired as I have confirmed that the heater is connected between +6V and the drain of the MOSFET. The source is connected directly to ground and a 10K resistor is in parallel between the gate and ground.

Comment: You still have not posted the heater resistance....

Comment: 10 hours since this was first posted and you still haven't supplied all the details asked.

Comment: The resistance of the heater when cold is 4 Ohms and does not change significantly when heating.

Comment: A reverse diode across the load is a good precaution. Heaters that are nominally resistive can also be nominally inductive by enough to cause inductive energy storage issues. Diodes are cheap.

Answer (score 1):

4 main choices:

- MOSFET is dead or misconnected
- 12V Power supply cannot supply about 12W needed.
- Buck converter cannot supply 1.5A / 9W needed.
- Load is not really 4 Ohms.

FET [datasheet here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/302/PHP79NQ08LT-842347.pdf)

**MOSFET is dead or misconnected**

Pinout is standard as all getout as per page 2 of data sheet.
On flat surface, metal down,  tab away from you legs' towards you connections are gds left to right.

In circuit, power on, short ds with wire.
If result is as when using FET fault is in buck or psu or FET drive.

Apply FET drive.
Measure voltage gs AT FET.
Should be 5V.

**12V Power supply cannot supply about 12W needed.**

Load 12V with 12 Ohms or less resistor.
Ensure 12V does not droop.
If supply has variable current limit it may be set to below what is needed.

**Buck converter cannot supply 1.5A / 9W needed.**

Supply 12V to buck converter.
Apply 4 Ohm load AT buck converter outputs across Vout-gnd.
Should supply load.

**Load is not really 4 Ohms.**

Apply 6V to load.
Measure current in load.
Measure voltage across load to check.
Apply Ohms law.

If all the above fails then you have a misconnection or are using insulating tubing in place of wire.

Remedy any inconsistencies found above.

Your circuit now works.
Q.E.D.